Tables are not colocated Error in Postgres
I have 2 tables in postgres, which are present in the separate schemas under same database.
While executing the SQL using the join between these 2 tables, getting the error as
table1 and table2 are not colocated
When checked the citus_shards table, both the tables are on same node, but the colocation id are different for both the tables.
citus.enable_repartition_joins is also set to true
Can someone please help?

Can someone please help?
